# svn command line update freezes. Must repeatedly issue the same commands

Tags: ubuntu, svn, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running svn 1.9.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.04 on Windows 10 (The version of Ubuntu you can get from the Windows Store).

I have been trying to retrieve files from a repository on a remote machine with svn checkout.  Unfortunately the checkout froze on me.  It pulled maybe 30 or 40 files and then just stopped updating.  Then it timed out.

So I tried just continuing with "svn update".  And it did resume for maybe 20 more files and then in froze again.

So now I am in this cycle where I keep hitting CTRL-C and then "svn update" to get the next "chunk" of files.  Sometimes the next update will be immediately frozen.  Other times it will manage to grab 5, 10, or even 50 files before freezing.   Still other times it will tell me that it is locked and so I have to do "svn cleanup" and then "svn update".

This is a really large repository and it's driving me nuts.  Is there some sort of connection timeout parameter that might be the culprit or something?

Meanwhile I can issue the same commands from a regular windows DOS box (which has SVN version 1.9.7) with no lockups whatsoever

Comment: I understand you're under [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). Could you try doing it from plain *Win* (or even using *Cywwin*)? Just to eliminate all potential failure candidates.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try investigating those.